# Empty all XML-nodes of a certain type using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I currently have a XML document built using the following structure:

```
<a>
     ....
     <b>
           <c>
           </c>
           <d>
           ....
           </d>
     </b>
</a>
<a>
   ....
```

I would like to parse this XML document using C# and output a document in which all the b-nodes are emptied, without losing my b-node. Thus creating the following result:

```
<a>
   ...
   <b />
</a>
<a>
   ...
```

Can anyone show me the way to do this?

Comment: This looks like a job for XSLT, any reason why you want to do this in code?

Comment: I'm used to programming in C# so I didn't think further than creating a console app using that language. But indeed, XSLT will also do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to XML would make this pretty simple:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var bs = doc.Descendants("b").ToList();
foreach (var b in bs)
{
    b.ReplaceNodes();
}
```

(Use `ReplaceAll` instead of `ReplaceNodes` if you want to remove the attributes within `b` nodes as well.)